# Как удалить аккаунт?

Tags: поддержка

[FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) прочитан, но не помог. В ответ на обращение в саппорт получил какую-то хрень с адреса "do-not-reply@stackexchange.com", очевидно, написанную роботом. Никакого отношения к моему запросу не имеющую. По приведённой выше картинке вроде получилось что-то удалить(?), но куки, сохранённые в другом браузере, позволяют мне заходить на якобы удалённый аккаунт. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё-таки удалиться?

Answer (score 5):

Вы сделали все верно. Через 23 часа ваша учётная запись будет удалена.

Comment: Похоже, что-то пошло не так ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вероятно, участник отменил удаление.

Comment: Просто в итоге обсуждение выглядит противоречиво.  )