# Как удалить свой профиль?

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника

Как удалить свой профиль, но не везде, а только на ruSo или на SO?

В этом вопросе [Как удалить аккаунт?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/533/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82)

Я не вижу четкого ответа.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить аккаунт?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/533/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82)

Comment: @Grundy, http://prntscr.com/es9fzg где?

Comment: @Grundy, тут не вижу четкого ответа на вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/533/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: Нужно полностью статью читать :-) Данный пункт только у тех пользователей, кто ничего не писал. В противном случае надо писать SO team

Comment: @Grundy, на русском языке есть какие-нибудь четкие инструкции?

Comment: Есть перевод статьи выше: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо

Comment: Решили удалиться не дойдя немного до 10К?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как описано в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

> Если с вашей учетной записи было отправлено не более одного голоса или сообщения:

то пункт *Удалить* будет в настройках профиля.

---

В противном случае нужно написать о проблеме через [форму обратной связи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) указав, что именно вы хотите сделать.